# How to record/store edits?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, programming-practices, patterns-and-practices

In many programs and web apps (stack exchange included) the program is able to backtrack what edits where made to the piece. My issue is similar: I want to be able to store a "timeline" of edits, where the user can go back and see what they typed at a specific time/when the typed certain words. What's the standard way to do this? Also, in things like google docs and other programs, they automatically "group" actions together (Like if I delete something by hitting back space 5 times, it knows I was deleting one word), any ideas on how to do that to?

Comment: With the "grouping" thing, there are probably events that fire with every key press. Once a "white space" occurs the event handler probably adds the last word to a list of some kind as well as keeping the word/character position.

Answer (score 1):

it's actually pretty simple

for every action the user makes you create a Undoable with 3 key methods

- undo() and redo(): for the actual undo and redo
- combine(Undoable) which creates a new Undoable of the 2 combined if they can be combined (otherwise null)

  the code will be something like:

  ```
  public Undoable combine(Undoable other){
      if(other instanceof UndoType){
          return new UndoType(this.insertedString+((UndoType)other).insertedString),position);
      }
      return null;
  }
  ```

then when you add the Undoable to the undo stack you check with the `combine` of the last undoable whether it can be combined